# Bot send message in while loop

Tags: discord.py

This is simplified code.

```
import time
import discord
x=0
while True:
   x=x+1
   time.sleep(100)
   #here I want to send 'x' to my discord channel
```

Assuming my bot is already configured and connected, I just need a function which will send message without a condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do that, you have to wait until bot is ready. So you can create this while loop inside the `on_ready` event. Then, you have to get the `discord.Channel` object that the message will be sent.

```py
x = 0
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(<channel id>)
    while True:
        x+=1
        time.sleep(100)
        await channel.send(x)
```

But I don't recommend to use while loops to do this. You can use `discord.ext.tasks` instead.

```py
from discord.ext import tasks
import discord

x = 0
@tasks.loop(seconds=100.0)
async def example():
    channel = client.get_channel(<channel id>)
    x+=1
    await channel.send(x)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    example.start() # This will start the loop when bot is ready.
```

For more information about `discord.ext.tasks`, you can visit the [Tasks API References](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html).